# Memory leak : Instruments vs Xcode Debug session

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks, instruments

I'm having some problems with iOS app I'm developping.

I have memory leaks and when trying to debug them I got a weird (to me) behaviour.

For debug purposes I did following :

1. Init a controller
2. do some stuff
3. remove the controller
4. Go to 1.

When doing this with XCode the memory footprint increase continuously with the time.

With the Intrusments' Allocation I do not get this memory footprint increase : It is relatively stable.

Do you have any idea what could explain this behaviour ?

FWW: The code I'm debugging is written in Objective-c with ARC.

Comment: Does Instruments show anything leaking?  If you run the static analyzer does it report potential leaks?

Comment: Check your build configuration in your scheme settings. Often Instruments is run with release build, as opposed to debug build when using the debugger. Also, double check your memory diagnostics (stuff like zombies can result in memory growth).

Comment: No leaks by the leak tool and nothing returned by the static analyzer. I test my app with debug & build release.